# How to store answer to the MCQ questions in sqlite DB

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Basically I have made an app which is a quiz type app. At every Activity 1 single question appears. Since I'm using `ViewPager` adapter and answers are to be chosen in the form of radio buttons, I am having trouble how to store the answers in the database for the all the questions. Please tell me how to make a database for this app and how to store ans of multiple questions.

This is my `fragment.xml`.

I've 38 similar fragments for each question to be displayed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.viewpager1.Layout_ Fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Question 1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Face"
        android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Small forehead"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Copper coloured with plenty of pimples"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Attractive good looking"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my `fragment.java` class.

Similarly I've 38 Fragments

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container, false);
    }
}
```

This is my `mainactivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_layout);
        initialisePaging();
    }

    private void initialisePaging()
    {
        List<Fragment> fragments =new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment1.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment2.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment3.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment4.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment5.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment6.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment7.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment8.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment9.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment10.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment11.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment12.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment13.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment14.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment15.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment16.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment17.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment18.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment19.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment20.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment21.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment22.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment23.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment24.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment25.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment26.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment27.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment28.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment29.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment30.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment31.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment32.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment33.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment34.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment35.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment36.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment37.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment38.class.getName()));
       mPagerAdapter = new com.example.android.viewpager1.PagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);
       ViewPager pager =(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
       pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    }
```

Now can anyone tell me what changes I should make  in `mainactivity.java` to make Sqlite database to store the values of radio buttons of all 38 questions and please tell me what columns and tables I should make in a database.

Comment: Remove your 38 fragments and 38 layouts first.